# Is $\mathrm{Graph}$ cartesian-closed?

Tags: ct.category-theory, graph-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

Let $\mathrm{Graph}$ be the category of simple, undirected graphs with [graph homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism). For any graphs $G, H$ we denote by $\text{Hom}(G, H)$ the set of graph homomorphisms $f:G\to H$. (Note that $\text{Hom}(G, H)$ can be empty, for instance if $\chi(G) > \chi(H)$.)

We can make $\text{Hom}(G, H)$ into a graph by saying that $f, g: G\to H$ form an edge if and only if $\{f(v), g(v)\}\in E(H)$ for all $v\in V(G)$.

Is $\mathrm{Graph}$ cartesian-closed?

Comment: This category lacks a terminal object.

Comment: @Wojowu To me it's ambiguous -- I don't know if a "simple, undirected graph" is allowed to have loops. There is a terminal object if loops are allowed.

Comment: @TimCampion A simple graph by definition has no loops.

Comment: Further, I'm afraid the obviously defined evaluation morphism is not a homomorphism, at least not for your definition of $Hom$ - if I'm not mistaken, the products in this category are defined as: $(v_1,w_1),(v_2,w_2)$ are connected in $G\times H$ iff $v_1,v_2$ are connected in $G$ and $w_1,w_2$ are connected in $H$. Applying this to $Hom(G,H)\times G$, we have edges between $(f,v)$ and $(g,w)$, and it won't necessarily be the case $f(v)$ and $g(w)$ are connected.

Comment: The linked Wikipedia article defines morphisms of graphs with loops, yet the post itself explicitly excludes loops by requiring the graphs to be simple.  Perhaps the notion of morphism of graph should be clarified, for there are other types of morphisms of (simple) graphs, e.g., those that allow edges to be collapsed even if loops are prohibited.

Comment: It also makes sense to point out that two related categories, that of directed graphs and undirected graphs (not necessarily simple) are cartesian closed because they are Grothendieck toposes by virtue of being categories of presheaves on a small category.

Comment: There has been some discussion on the n-Category Café about this [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/04/colouring_a_graph.html) and [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/12/graph_colouring_and_cartesian.html).

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Sorry to bring this up years later, but I clarified in my newly edited post that although directed multigraphs form a presheaf category, undirected multigraphs do not, and in fact are not cartesian closed. Undirected multigraphs are naturally a reflective subcategory of a presheaf category, though.

Comment: @TimCampion: I am no longer certain what was the notion of an undirected graph that I had in mind, but you list three cartesian closed categories (13, 14, and 15) in your list, and there are also categories of undirected graphs (not in your list) that are in fact presheaf categories, e.g., ribbon graphs (alias fat graphs): https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ribbon%20graph.

Comment: I should really remove any suggestion that my list is exhaustive. Also it's worth pointing out that the definition in the question of the internal hom turns out to be incorrect for any of the categories considered here. For those which are cartesian closed, the vertices of the internal hom are arbitrary functions between the vertices. There is an edge from $f$ to $g$ if there for every edge $x \to x'$ there is an edge $f(x) \to g(x')$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are many categories of graphs, so perhaps it's best to take a synoptic view (though far from exhaustive).

The table below surveys several categories of directed multigraphs (DM), directed graphs (DG), undirected multigraphs (UM), and undirected graphs (UG).  The asterisks indicate the ones which are *not* cartesian closed. There are many other interesting categories of graphs, some of which are mentioned in the comments.

The category of simple graphs is (16) in the chart and list below. It is not cartesian closed. But a slight modification of this category -- (15) below -- with equivalent objects but where morphisms are allowed to collapse an edge to a point, *is* cartesian closed.

However, the description of the internal hom given in the question is incorrect for any of the categories below (though it's a reasonable guess!). The internal hom $H^G$ has for vertices all functions $V(G) \to V(H)$ between vertex sets. An edge from $f$ to $g$ is a rule which assigns, to every edge $x \to y$ in $G$, an edge $f(x) \to g(y)$ in $H$ (of course, in graphs which are not multigraphs, there is always at most one edge $f(x) \to g(y)$ to choose, so that this is just a condition). This should be compared to the internal hom in chain complexes, $G$-representations, etc, where maps from the terminal / unit object are not quite the same as "points" or "elements" in the most obvious sense and the internal hom ends up bigger than one might think. The graph homomorphisms may be recovered from this by homming in from the terminal object. A subtle point is that e.g. if we dress up a simple graph to be a reflexive graph (moving from (16) to (15) or eqivalently  (14) as suggested above), it's important to remember that we've done this when computing the internal hom via the above description, or when mapping in from the terminal object to recover the homomorphisms.

\begin{array}{lcccc}
& DM & DG & UM & UG \\
\text{Loops allowed} 
& 1 & 5 & 9* & 13\\
\text{Loops allowed and reflexive} 
& 2 & 6 & 10* & 14\\
\text{strictly reflexive} 
& 3* & 7 & 11* & 15 \\
\text{Loops not allowed} 
& 4* & 8* & 12* & 16*
\end{array}
The concepts of reflexive and strictly reflexive graphs are distinct for multigraphs, but the same for graphs, which I forgot when writing. Nevertheless, the following should be accurate, just with unnecessarily complicated discussion for (7) (equivalent to (6)) and (15) (equivalent to (14)).

A particular salient point to keep in mind is:

> Even if you're interested in, say, simple graphs, the notion of graph homomorphism might not be the correct notion of morphism to use. Changing the morphisms may be equivalent to equipping your graph with a bit of "dummy data" and using the resulting standard notion of homomorphism sometimes results in a better-behaved notion of morphism.

**Warmup:**

We're going to systematically go through all these different categories of graphs. To motivate the approach, consider for example the category of **(1) directed multigraphs where loops are allowed**. Such a graph $G$ comprises two sets $V(G),E(G)$ of *vertices* and *edges* respectively, and two functions $E(G) \rightrightarrows V(G)$, one of which sends an edge to its starting vertex, and the other to its ending vertex. This is data is nicely summarized by saying that we have a presheaf on the category $\mathcal I$ with two objects and two nonidentity morphisms which looks like this [1]:

$$V \rightrightarrows E$$

Presheaves come with a natural notion of morphism, and it agrees with the usual notion of a graph homomorphism. So we see that the category of directed graphs where loops are allowed is equivalent to the category of presheaves on the category $\mathcal I$. Therefore, as Dmitri Pavlov observes in the comments, it is cartesian closed.

**Categories of Presheaves:**

In the following, we'll consider presheaves on $\mathcal I$ as well as three other categories which we'll call $\mathcal R, \mathcal U, \mathcal T$, each of which has two objects $V,E$ and a finite number of morphisms. The categories of presheaves on these categories will be denoted $Psh(\mathcal I), Psh(\mathcal R),Psh(\mathcal U),Psh(\mathcal T)$.

- The category $\mathcal I$ which we've already seen, can alternatively be described as (a skeleton of) the category of linearly ordered sets of cardinality 1 or 2, and all injective order-preserving maps. This category has 2 objects and 2 nonidentity morphisms. A presheaf on $\mathcal I$ is a directed graph.
- The category $\mathcal R$, (a skeleton of) the category of linearly ordered sets of cardinality 1 or 2 and all order-preserving maps. This category has 2 objects and 5 nonidentity morphisms. A presheaf on $\mathcal R$ is a directed graph equipped with a distinguished loop at each vertex (and homomorphisms are required to carry distinguished loops to distinguished loops). Such a graph is called a **(2) reflexive, directed multigraph where loops are allowed**.
- The category $\mathcal U$, (a skeleton of) the category of sets of cardinality 1 or 2 and all injective maps. This category has 2 objects and 3 nonidentity morphisms. A presheaf on $\mathcal U$ is a directed graph equipped with an involution on its edges which swaps the endpoints. We'll see that such structures are related to undirected multigraphs.
- The category $\mathcal T$, (a skeleton of) the catgeory of sets of cardinality 1 or 2 and all maps. This category has 2 objects and 6 nonidentity morphisms. A presheaf on $\mathcal T$ is like a presheaf on $\mathcal U$, in addition has a designated loop at each vertex which is fixed by the involution. We'll see that such structures are related to reflexive, undirected multigraphs.

**Generalities on Presheaf Categories:**
We will use the following facts:

- Every presheaf category is cartesian closed.
- Let $\mathcal D$ be a full reflective subcategory of a presheaf category $Psh(\mathcal C)$ containing the representable presheaves. Then $\mathcal D$ is cartesian closed if and only if $\mathcal D$ is an *exponential ideal* (i.e. $Y \in \mathcal D, X \in Psh(\mathcal C) \Rightarrow Y^X \in \mathcal D$).
- Let $S \subseteq Mor (Psh(\mathcal C))$ be a set of morphisms, and let $\mathcal D \subseteq Psh(\mathcal C)$ be the right orthogonal complement to $S$. Suppose that $\mathcal D$ contains the representables. Then $\mathcal D$ is cartesian closed if and only if, for every representable $c$, every $i \in I$, and every $Y \in \mathcal D$, $Y$ is right orthogonal to $i \times 1_c$.

Below, all the categories we consider are full subcategories of presheaf categories conatining the representables (there are always just two representables --  the free point $V$ and the free edge $E$) and defined by explicit orthogonality conditions. In each case, to check the last condition for cartesian closedness, it will suffice to consider the case where $c$ is the free edge $E$. This can always be done by hand. Since it's hard to create the appropriate images and to post them here, I will just report what the verdict ends up being for cartesian closure.

**Directed Graphs as Presheaves:**

1. As we've seen, the category of **directed multigraphs with loops allowed** and homomorphisms is just $Psh(\mathcal I)$. As a presheaf category, it is cartesian closed. This is the category theorist's default notion of "graph".
2. As we've seen, the category of **reflexive directed multigraphs with loops allowed** is just $Psh(\mathcal R)$. As a presheaf category, it is cartesian closed. This type of graph is also commonly used in category theory.
3. The category of **strictly reflexive directed multigraphs** is the full subcategory of $Psh(\mathcal R)$ where there are no loops besides the designated ones (whenver I say "strictly reflexive" in this answer, that is what I mean -- reflexive, and the only loops are the designated ones). This is the right orthogonal complement to the map from the free loop to the terminal object. The product of this map with the free edge is not orthogonal to all strictly reflexive multigraphs, so strictly reflexive multigraphs are *not* cartesian closed.
4. The category of **loop-free directed multigraphs** may be regarded as a full subcategory of the category of directed multigraphs where loops are allowed. It lacks a terminal object, so is *not* cartesian closed.

Note that the objects of (3) and (4) are equivalent -- even if you don't like loops, you might pretend they're there for the sake of defining morphisms.

5. The category of **directed graphs where loops are allowed** is the full subcategory of directed multigraphs which is right orthogonal to the map from the graph that looks like this $\bullet \rightrightarrows \bullet$ to the free edge $\bullet \to \bullet$. This is an exponential ideal, so this category is cartesian closed.
6. The category of **reflexive directed graphs where loops are allowed** is the full subcategory of reflexive directed multigraphs which is right orthogonal to a similar map as in (5) (if we take the convention that designated loops are suppressed in drawings). This is an exponential ideal, so this category is cartesian closed.
7. The category of **strictly reflexive directed graphs** is the full subcategory of reflexive directed multigraphs which is right orthogonal to both the morphism of (6) and the morphism of (3). The morphism of (3), after taking the product with the free edge, was not orthogonal to every strictly reflexive directed multigraph, but it *is* orthogonal to every strictly reflexive directed graph. The other morphism also works out as in (6), so this category is an exponential ideal and hence cartesian closed.
8. The category of **loop-free directed graphs** may be regarded as a full subcategory of the category of directed graphs. It lacks a terminal object, and so is *not* cartesian closed.

Note again that the objects of (7) and (8) are equivalent. I think graph theorists are generally more likely to think about graphs as described in (8), but this time the trick of changing the morphisms to those of (7) buys us cartesian closure.

**Undirected Graphs as Presheaves:**

9. The category of **undirected multigraphs where loops are allowed** may be embedded into $Psh(\mathcal U)$ in at least two ways. The most obvious way is to do the obvious thing for vertices, and for each undirected edge, to put in two directed edges, exchanged by the involution. Unfortunately, this yields "spurious" morphisms which exchange the two copies we get of each loop. To fix this, we modify the construction by putting in only one directed edge for each loop, and have it fixed by the involution. This gives the right notion of morphism. Thus undirected multigraphs where loops are allowed form the full subcateory of $Psh(\mathcal U)$ right orthogonal to the map from the free loop (which is a point with two loops exchanged by the involution) to the terminal object (which is a point with a loop which is fixed by the involution). This is not an exponential ideal, and hence *not* cartesian closed.
10. The category of **reflexive undirected multigraphs where loops are allowed** is the full subcategory of $Psh(\mathcal T)$ defined by a similar orthogonality condition to (9). This category is not an exponential ideal, and so *not* cartesian closed.
11. The category of **strictly reflexive undirected multigraphs** is the full subcategory of $Psh(\mathcal T)$ satisfying the orthogonality condition of (10) as well as one similar to (3). It is not an exponential ideal, and so *not* cartesian closed.
12. The category of **loop-free undirected multigraphs** is the full subcategory of $Psh(\mathcal T)$ satisfying the orthogonality conditions of (11), plus one similar to (4). This category lacks a terminal object, and so is *not* cartesian closed.

Again the objects of (11) and (12) are equivalent.

13. The category of **undirected graphs where loops are allowed** is the full subcategory of $Psh(\mathcal U)$ which is right orthogonal to the map of (9) plus a map analogous to (5). As in (7), the non-multi-ness comes to the rescue -- this is an exponential ideal, and hence cartesian closed.
14. The category of **reflexive undirected graphs where loops are allowed** is the full subcategory of $Psh(\mathcal T)$ which is right orthogonal to maps analogous to (13). Similarly to (13), this is an exponential ideal, and hence cartesian closed.
15. The category of **strictly reflexive undirected graphs** is the full subcategory of $Psh(\mathcal T)$ which is right orthogonal to the maps of (14), plus the map of (11). This is an exponential ideal, and hence cartesian closed.
16. The category of **loop-free undirected graphs** may be regarded as a full subcategory of the category of undirected graphs where loops are allowed. This category lacks a terminal object, and hence is *not* cartesian closed.

(16) is the category of the question. As Wojowu observed in the comments, it lacks a terminal object, and so is not cartesian closed for trivial reasons. But (15) has equivalent objects to (16), with the morphisms differing only in that we allow an edge to be contracted to a point. With this change, the category becomes cartesian closed.

[1] Note the reversal in direction of the arrows because a presheaf is a functor $(V\rightrightarrows E)^{op} \to Set$ -- the reversal comes from the "op". The "op" is a matter of convention, but in this case is nice because it allows the definitions of the categories we use to be a bit slicker.

Comment: The categories of graphs which are functor categories are of course toposes. If I'm not mistaken, the localizations yielding the other categories of graphs exhibit them as [quasitoposes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quasitopos) (except for the ones which are not cartesian closed).

Comment: Something else I can't resist mentioning -- for whatever flavor of graph one is interested in, so long as one allows morphisms which collapse an edge to a point, it ought to turn out that a [subquotient](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subquotient) of a graph $G$ is the same thing as a [graph minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$.

Comment: Lovely answer, but one terminological quibble.  You write “For a category theorist, the default category of graphs to use is the category of reflexive, directed multigraphs where loops are allowed.” — really?  In my (mostly category-theoretic) experience, these are always called *reflexive graphs*, and unqualified *graphs* means these without the reflexivity, i.e. the second definition you give.

Comment: @Peter Fair point! But I think this is _purely_ an artifact of the fact that the non-reflexive version is slightly easier to define. It seems to me the categorical properties of reflexive graphs are _always_ better than non-reflexive graphs. The only time I ever find myself thinking about the category of non-reflexive graphs is when I think the difference between the reflexive and non-reflexive categories might not matter and so I can simplify my exposition of a point by not delving into the distinction. Maybe the default should be non-reflexive objects but with reflexive morphisms :).

Comment: Interesting!  For my part, I’ve often worked in settings where one really wants non-reflexive graphs (with their genuine non-reflexive morphisms), so I definitely don’t think of the traditional convention as an artefact of simplicity/convenience.  Or rather, I think the extra simplicity is in some ways a deep not just a superficial difference: the indexing category for non-reflexive graphs is posetal, is an inverse/direct category (not just a Reedy category), and so on, making its diagram category better-behaved in a range of ways and settings.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I agree; in my entire experience of category theory unqualified "graph" always means the non-reflexive version, and I very much disagree that this is just because it's easier to define.  Non-reflexive graphs are much more natural as, for instance, the domain of the monad for free categories.  In some cases this can have serious mathematical consequences, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.3961.

Comment: Which isn't to say that we never *use* reflexive graphs; the point is terminological.

Comment: @MikeShulman Interesting! In fact, the domain of the free category monad was actually something I had in mind when thinking that _reflexive_ graphs where more natural! For instance, in [simplicial localization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+localization#standard_simplicial_localization) it's the adjunction with reflexive graphs that's used.

Comment: @TimCampion A classic distinction between these two categories as toposes was made by Lawvere in [this short paper](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/9/tr9abs.html).  And to bring out Mike's example: the free category monad on the category of non-reflexive graphs is a cartesian monad, but this is not so over reflexive graphs (since the underlying functor doesn't preserve pullbacks).

Comment: In this last rewrite, I initially had the intention of being comprehensible to non-category-theorists, but quickly gave up on that as I was still thinking through the results myself. At this point, it's probably long enough that few folks -- category theorists or not -- are going to be reading it! So I probably won't attempt to make it more comprehensible; I just felt compelled to make it correct.

Comment: Suppose one defines morphisms from $X$ to $Y$ as subgraphs of $X\times Y$ whose projection to $X$ is an isomorphism (version: bijection on vertices and, for multigraphs, injection on edges). Does one obtain one of the notions of morphism from your list?

Comment: Still another version would be to define the bicategory of graph relations as just arbitrary subgraphs of $X\times Y$ and then define maps as adjoint pairs of relations, as usual.

Comment: Note also a resemblance to sets with a Heyting-valued equality as considered by Higgs and Fourman&Scott. There, only symmetry and transitivity is required, with "$x=x$" interpreted as "$x\in X$" or "$x$ is defined". Since they obtain a topos in that case, something similar should be doable for not necessarily reflexive graphs too.

Comment: Interesting! Dmitri Pavlov points out some other presheaf categories of graphs in the comments above. The list in this answer is obviously not exhaustive--the examples were chosen primarily to include the categories most use by category theorists (1,2), the one from the question (16), a good "correction" to that category (15), and then everything in between. I don't think the categories you bring up are on this list.

Comment: Note to self: an example of a binary product not preserved by the free category monad $F$ on reflexive graphs (as mentioned by @AlexanderCampbell above) is the product of the walking arrow $E$ with itself: In $F(E) \times F(E)$ there is one "diagonal" morphism, while in $F(E \times E)$ there are three -- two composite and one atomic. Non-reflexive graphs elude this issue because in this setting, $E \times E$ doesn't have any non-diagonal arrows to compose, and also because $F^{nonreflexive}$ doesn't preserve the terminal object, so preserving pullbacks wouldn't imply preserving binary products

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, the interested reader of this question can find more details in the following paper, which addresses in Section 4 the topic in question: "[Categories of graphs are cartesian closed.](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/9/1.pdf)" There, the author considers four different categories of graphs. The paper follows a relatively similar exposition to Tim Campion's answer.

```
@article{Bumby1986,
  title     = {Categorical constructions in graph theory},
  author    = {Richard T. Bumby and Dana May Latch},
  year      = 1986,
  journal   = {International Journal of Mathematics and Mathematical Sciences},
  url       = {https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/9/1.pdf}
  volume    = 9,
  number    = 1,
  pages     = {1--16},
  doi       = {10.1155/s0161171286000017}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in the following thesis "[Functorial Approach to Graph and Hypergraph Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.02574)" by M. Schmidt looks at when categories of uniform hypergraphs have exponentials. In particular he gives the following conceptual equations:

Graphs + Exponentials = (X,M)-Graphs

Graphs + Effective Equivalence Relations = (X.M)-Graphs

where Graphs is a category of uniform hypergraphs and (X,M)-graphs is a category of presheaves on two objects (containers for vertices and arrows). I can't remember (or quickly find) if he looks at exponentials in these categories.